# Using scanf on a large amount of data

Tags: scanf

I have to read in data in this format:

3000    100
14.283,65.966,49.807,43.363,71.496,61.712,7.0562,24.365,50.623,38.299,32.566,89.61,20.412,

I can easily read in the first 3 numbers, but when I try to use scanf in a loop it just keeps reading the 14.283 over and over.

The way I am inputting the data (this is non-negotiable) is by piping the results of "cat" on the file containing the data into my program using bash I/O

If I were to make a guess...I'd say it doesn't like the [^,] and is ignoring all the data past that point?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ){

    int total, rows, columns;
    float number;
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    scanf("%d", &columns);
    printf("%d\n%d\n", rows, columns);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        scanf("%f[^,]", &number);
        printf("%f\n", number);


    }

}
```

Comment: you can read the input as string and then convert to number right

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this isn't regex, but it works

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    scanf("%f %c", &number2, &comma);
    printf("%f\n", number2);


}
```

number2 takes the float value, comma eats the comma

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way

```
char character[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    scanf("%f%[^,]", &number2,character);
    printf("%f\n", number2);
}
```

or by simply use suppression operator

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    scanf("%f%*[^,]", &number2);
    printf("%f\n", number2);
}
```